# How can I activate the Google Chrome password generator for my password input field?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, passwords, generator

I have noticed on some websites google is asking me if i want to use a password generated by Chrome.

It doesnt happen with my own input field.

How can i make this work?

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g57Ax.png)

Comment: I don't know about how to make it, but I would recommend you to not use this Chrome password generator.

Comment: try `autocomplete='new-password'` in you input field

Comment: Vaibhav Vishal .. right answer

Comment: @J.Smith why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 11):

Based on chromium; this should work : (the suggest password comes after already known passwords for that site)

```
<form id="login" action="signup.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="username">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
</form>
```

more examples : https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands

Comment: Can we trigger that password suggestion box using javascript ?

Comment: You -most likely- cannot do that and I would suggest against using javascript to call on this functionality, if the browser decides its a bad idea to show password functionality there might be a good reason.

Comment: I just want to show suggested password. Not user's saved password. So that user just click on it without manually typing password. If it is possible via javascript, then please help me.